# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js)

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working with angular and node, when i run the command `npm start` i get this error

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-3!./src/styles.scss)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\node_modules@angular\material\prebuilt-themes\indigo-pink.css'
> at Object.openSync (fs.js:457:3)
> at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:359:35)
> at Storage.provideSync (...\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:109:13)
> at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (...\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:289:32)
> at Observable._subscribe (...\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\webpack-input-host.js:35:51)

I have tried view some similar post but no solution work. My node.js  version is

> v12.16.1

My angular version is

> Angular CLI: 9.1.9
> Node: 12.16.1
> OS: win32 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use node 10 as it more suitable for angular 9. You can easily do that using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Then you can try below steps,

- rm -rf node_modules
- npm i --save-exact
- ng s

Answer (score 4):

If you are using angular and if following is not working.

```
@import "../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
```

**then try the following inside styles array in angular.json file**

"styles": [   `"src/styles.scss",`  `"node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",`  `"node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css",`
]

**It is a working example.**

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the postcss with the CSS module is not configured or installed. I resolved the issue by installing this package:

```
npm install babel-plugin-react-css-modules --save
```

You can readmore about resolving the issue here:
https://dev.to/daveirvine/postcss-with-css-modules-andreact-51ln